# как получить данные с сайта с помощью xPath?

Tags: python, lxml

```
import requests
import urllib.request

from lxml.html import fromstring

URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/'
HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

list_html = HTML.read().decode('utf-8')
parser = fromstring(list_html)

for elem in parser.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/div[1]/article[1]/a[2]/h3'):
    print(elem.text)
```

**UPDATE 3:**

> Не получилось сохранить `іngredients`, в БД попадает пустая строка

```
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse
import sqlite3
import time 

WEBSITE = 'http://allrecipes.com'    

def correct_str(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()

def save(title,ingredients,photo_url):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO content(title,ingredients,img) VALUES(?,?,?)", (title,ingredients,photo_url,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

for i in range(1, 11):
    URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/?page=' + str(i)
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    page = parse(HTML).getroot()

    # пропускаем видео
    for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article[not(contains(@class, "video-card"))]/a[1]'):
        href = WEBSITE + elem.get('href')
        title = correct_str(elem.find('h3').text)

        if title == 'Allrecipes Magazine':
            continue

        recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
        photo_url = recipe_page.xpath('//img[@class="rec-photo"]')[0].get('src')

        # массив с ингредиентами
        ingredients = recipe_page.xpath('//ul[contains(@id, "lst_ingredients")]/li/label/span/text()')
        ingredients = filter(lambda s: 'Add all ingredients' not in s, map(correct_str, ingredients))

        # массив с последовательностью приготовления
        directions = recipe_page.xpath('//span[@class="recipe-directions__list--item"]/text()')
        directions = map(correct_str, directions)

        times = recipe_page.xpath('//span[@class="ready-in-time"]/text()') 

        servings = recipe_page.xpath('//span[@ng-bind="adjustedServings"]/text()')

        cals = recipe_page.xpath('//*[@id="nutrition-button"]/span[1]/span[1]/text()')

        author = recipe_page.xpath('//*[@class="submitter__name"]/text()')[0]

        #comment_author = recipe_page.xpath('//*[@class="submitter__description"]/text()')

        print('Страница:', i)
        print('Название:', title)
        print('Автор:', author)
        #print('Коментарь от автора:', comment_author)
        print('Ссылка:', href)
        print('Фото:', photo_url)
        print('Время:', times)
        print('Порции:', servings)
        print('Калории', cals)
        print('Ингредиенты:', '; '.join(ingredients))
        print(' ----------------------')
        print('Шаги:')
        print('\n\n'.join(directions))
        print(' ======================\n')
        ing = '; '.join(ingredients)

        save(title,ing,photo_url)
```

Comment: обновил ответ (изображение, ингредиенты и т.д.)

Comment: Вопрос плавно перетёк в вопрос типа «пишите код вместе со мной»...

Comment: все решил задачу )

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, а почему xpath возвращает пустой массив `//span[@ng-bind="adjustedServings"]/text()` хотя данные по даному адресу присутствуют

Comment: @Surfer значение в этот спан подставляется только в результате выполнения javascript-кода в браузере. На питоне повторить такое поведение - отдельная, не слишком простая задача (например, можно подключать webkit-движок и т.п.).

Comment: понял, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том, что исходная структура HTML-документа, полученная в ответе от сервера, при отображении в браузере может быть изменена скриптами. Ваш XPath-запрос должен работать именно с исходной структурой. Ее можно посмотреть, например, в отладчике Chrome на вкладке Network.

```
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse

URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/'
HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

page = parse(HTML).getroot();

for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article/a/h3/text()'):
    print(elem.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip())
```

А еще можно использовать функцию `cssselect` (необходимо установить пакет `cssselect`). Часто CSS-селектором проще воспользоваться, чем XPath.

```
for elem in page.cssselect('#grid h3'):
    print(elem.text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip())
```

---

**UPDATE** Вывод ссылок с перебором страниц:

```
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse

SITE = 'http://allrecipes.com'

for i in range(1, 6):
    URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/?page=' + str(i)
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    page = parse(HTML).getroot();

    for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article/a[1]'):
        href = SITE + elem.get('href')
        title = elem.find('h3').text.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
        print('Названия:', title, '\nСсылка: ', href, '\n ----------------------')
```

---

**UPDATE2.** Загрузка фото, ингредиентов, последовательности шагов:

```
import urllib.request
from lxml.html import parse

WEBSITE = 'http://allrecipes.com'

def correct_str(s):
    return s.encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()

for i in range(1, 11):
    URL = 'http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/?page=' + str(i)
    HTML = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)

    page = parse(HTML).getroot()

    # пропускаем видео
    for elem in page.xpath('//*[@id="grid"]/article[not(contains(@class, "video-card"))]/a[1]'):
        href = WEBSITE + elem.get('href')
        title = correct_str(elem.find('h3').text)

        if title == 'Allrecipes Magazine':
            continue

        recipe_page = parse(urllib.request.urlopen(href)).getroot()
        photo_url = recipe_page.xpath('//img[@class="rec-photo"]')[0].get('src')

        # массив с ингредиентами
        ingredients = recipe_page.xpath('//ul[contains(@id, "lst_ingredients")]/li/label/span/text()')
        ingredients = filter(lambda s: 'Add all ingredients' not in s, map(correct_str, ingredients))

        # массив с последовательностью приготовления
        directions = recipe_page.xpath('//span[@class="recipe-directions__list--item"]/text()')
        directions = map(correct_str, directions)

        print('Страница:', i)
        print('Название:', title)
        print('Ссылка:', href)
        print('Фото:', photo_url)
        print('Ингредиенты:', ', '.join(ingredients))
        print(' ----------------------')
        print('Шаги:')
        print('\n\n'.join(directions))
        print(' ======================\n')
```

Comment: Раз вы css-селектор так оформили, можно было и xpath записать как: `//*[@id="grid"]//h3/text()` :)

Comment: @gil9red да, конечно :)

Comment: отлично ) а если нужно ещё ссылку получить из тега 'a'
`//*[@id="grid"]/div[1]/article[1]/a[2]`

Comment: @Surfer `elem.get('href')` (только `text()` из xpath-запроса убрать)

Comment: @Surfer обновил ответ.

Comment: а если ещё парсить данные из следующей страницы, пока `page` не будет равна 5   

`http://allrecipes.com/recipes/79/desserts/?page=2`

Comment: да, такое трудно сделать

Comment: @Surfer добавил